# Java memory issues

Tags: java

I am trying to run my Minecraft server on my new host, but I keep getting this error.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

I have the memory (over 2G).

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2560        354       2205          0          0         51
-/+ buffers/cache:        302       2257
```

I am using this to launch the jar. It works when I use -Xmx1G but I am trying to use all 2G (or at least close to it).

```
#!/bin/sh
java -server -Xms256M -Xmx1300M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this a 32-bit JVM or a 64-bit JVM?

Answer (score 0):

Your system and Java VM need RAM too. You can't allocate entire RAM for Minecraft. Run it with lower Xmx or upgrade your RAM.

Anyway, 1 GB RAM server should handle at least 30 players at once.